# Path to user directory when username is unknown

Tags: icloud, finder, path, dropbox

Some colleagues and I have our cloud storage (e.g. Dropbox) syncing to our macs.

The local path to a particular folder in our synchronised cloud storage looks like `/Users/{$USERNAME}/CloudSync/Projects/Hello World/`

When we share links with each other we currently share the links provided by our cloud service which opens the app or website to view them. It would be great if we could just share a path to our local copies with each other, but obviously I don't want to have to manually type their usernames into the path each time. Is there some sort of alias for username that can be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard path to `/Users/[current user]` is tilde ~

So the path to `/Users/{$USERNAME}/CloudSync/Projects/Hello World/` for any user is

`~/CloudSync/Projects/Hello World/`